# Садить/сажать

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каких случаях пишется **САДИТЬ**, а в каких **САЖАТЬ**? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В нормативном тексте - всегда сажать во всех значениях, связаннных с процессом посадки/сажания.

Садить - народно-разговорная форма к сажать. Поэтому и используется главным образои при передаче разговорной речи.
Кроме того, у "садить" есть ещё два значания, с процессом сажания напрямую не свазанние.
~1. Сниженное к ударить, стукнуть и т.д, в основном в однократной форме - садануть кулаком по столу.  
~2. безличное: резко ощущаться (в отношении запаха и т.д.) С кухни садило гарью.

Comment: А вариант САДИТЬ/САЖАТЬ в тюрьму?

Comment: Только сажать в тбрьму. Садить - даже не слышал. Посадить в тюрьму - это да. Но не "салить"